# Problems compiling Handbrake: syntax error near unexpected token `CSS,'

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, video

I tried to compile Handbrake 0.10.5 on Raspberry Pi, Raspbian Jessie,  following [this guide](https://errorin10.wordpress.com/2016/03/08/compiling-handbrake-0-10-5-on-a-raspberry-pi-3/), and encountered several issues. The first one was

```
./stdio.h:477:1: error: ‘gets’ undeclared here (not in a function)
_GL_WARN_ON_USE (gets, “gets is a security hole – use fgets instead”);
```

which I solved by removing the warning a redefining `gets` in `build/contrib/m4/m4-1.4.16/lib/stdio.in.h`:

```
...
#undef gets
// _GL_WARN_ON_USE (gets, "gets is a security hole - use fgets instead");
#define gets(a) fgets( a, sizeof(*(a)), stdin)
...
```

However I got stuck further in the process with the following error:

```
...
./configure: line 12586: syntax error near unexpected token `CSS,'
./configure: line 12586: `  PKG_CHECK_MODULES(CSS, $CSS_REQUIRES)'
../contrib/libdvdread/module.rules:2: recipe for target > 'contrib/libdvdread/.stamp.configure' failed
make: *** [contrib/libdvdread/.stamp.configure] Error 2
```

Any ideas how to get past this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Handbrake 0.10.5, but the current version on github worked great.

```
git clone https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake.git
cd HandBrake
./configure --enable-x265 --enable-fdk-aac --enable-libav-aac
cd build
make
sudo make install
```